# splitting a string of variable length

Tags: r, regex

I have a string of length 410 (i.e. number of characters). I want to split it into substrings in the following manner:

1. each substring must have characters less than 260
2. each substring should end with a correct word (or fully spelled). For example: `this is a test string`, cannot have substring like `this is a test st`, it should be like `this is a test`
3. You cannot drop off the characters, so when substrings are joined together, they should read the same as original string.

reproducible data:

```r
ex_str = "This has an advantage of avoiding name conflicts i.e. what if you have a function named `DataFrame()` in your global environment. Using `pandas.DataFrame()` ensures that right function is called. To build on it further, python also provides an option of importing a function with your name of choice i.e. `import pandas as pd`. Now to call out `pandas` internal functions you can use `pd` like `pd.DataFrame()`"
nchar(ex_str)
#> [1] 410
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Expected output:

```r
s1 = "This has an advantage of avoiding name conflicts i.e. what if you have a function named `DataFrame()` in your global environment. Using `pandas.DataFrame()` ensures that right function is called."
s2 = "To build on it further, python also provides an option of importing a function with your name of choice i.e. `import pandas as pd`. Now to call out `pandas` internal functions you can use `pd` like `pd.DataFrame()`"
nchar(s1) #nchar() should be less than 260
#> [1] 195
nchar(s2)
#> [1] 214
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

This problem seems too difficult for me to get started, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried to do so far? I would suggest looking into using regular expressions to identify the location of word boundaries, then some code to split the string at the largest word boundary location that is less than 260.

Comment: Your expected output is not correct given your input and your constraints. Why did you stop at 195 for `s1`? It should be obvious that the next word (`"To"`) is not over 65 characters, so there must be more constraints that you haven't passed. (Realize that what is happening here is similar to what LaTeX does in its default full-justification: splitting sentences based on kern-width and *optimizing* the amount of squish-or-stretch required for each row of characters. I emphasize *optimize* because it truly is a mathematical optimization.

Answer (score 1):

```r
spl <- strsplit(ex_str, " ")[[1]]
out <- c()
while (length(spl) > 0) {
  ind <- which((cumsum(nchar(spl)) + seq_along(spl)) > 260)[1]
  if (is.na(ind)) ind <- length(spl) + 1L
  if (ind == 1L) {
    warning("first word is too long, adding anyway", call. = FALSE)
    out <- c(out, spl[1])
    spl <- spl[-1]
  } else {
    out <- c(out, paste(spl[seq_len(ind-1)], collapse = " "))
    spl <- spl[-seq_len(ind-1)]
  }
}

nchar(out)
# [1] 253 156

out
# [1] "This has an advantage of avoiding name conflicts i.e. what if you have a function named `DataFrame()` in your global environment. Using `pandas.DataFrame()` ensures that right function is called. To build on it further, python also provides an option of"
# [2] "importing a function with your name of choice i.e. `import pandas as pd`. Now to call out `pandas` internal functions you can use `pd` like `pd.DataFrame()`"
```